# Get all values from Bootstrap Dropdown using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get all the values in a Bootstrap Dropdown Menu by using a JavaScript function. When I select something, I manage that the selection stays. Nevertheless, unlike the html dropdown menu with `<select>` and `<option>`, where I am able to get all the possible options that the user can choose from, I neither find anything on the web nor by try and error to get all the values that are in the bootstrap drop-down menu.

```
<div class="dropdown">
<button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
Dropdown
<span class="caret"></span>
</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown-menu"> <!-- aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1"> -->
{% for instance in leaderboardDictionaries %}
    {% for category, userDictionary in instance.items %}
        <li><a href="#">{{category}}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
</div>
```

In my javascript function, the first thing I do, is making sure that the selection stays. Then I want to get all the possible 'options'. But my code obviously is not right.

```
<script>
$(".dropdown-menu li").click(function(){
var selText = $(this).text();
$(this).parents('.dropdown').find('.dropdown-toggle').html(selText+' <span class="caret"></span>');
var availableOptions = $('.dropdown-menu li option');
alert(availableOptions[1]);
});
</script>
```

Comment: you mean without jquery?

Comment: `var availableOptions = $('.dropdown-menu li option');` – there are no `option` elements inside the `li`.

Comment: Sorry, JQuery is also okay. Would be interested in either solution (using javascript or JQuery)

Comment: Okay --- if there are no 'option' elements inside the li --- how do I get the available 'options'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work fine for you.

```
$('#dropdown-menu li').on('click', function(){

  $("#dropdown-menu li").each(function(){
    console.log($(this).text()); //do anything with the values
  });

});
```

Comment: Worked for me. THX. I stored it in an array like this:
    `var testArray = new Array();`
    `$('#dropdown-menu li').each(function(){
    testArray.push($(this).text());
   });`

Comment: Awesome. Glad it helped.